# Updating string fields in Firestore via Console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

When using the Google Firebase [Cloud Firestore Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/), is there a way to *preserve line-breaks* when manually updating the value of a document-field of type `string` via the web-interface?

As far as I can tell, whenever I try to update a string field via the console, all line-breaks disappear.

Comment: Yes, I'm experiencing this problem too, I think this is a bug (or at least a severe limitation) with the Console